# laravel get the id of the currently logged in user using Eloquent auth

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using `Laravel 4.2` in my web application and I'm trying to get the id of the currently logged in user. This is how i have done it in `UserController.php`.

```
if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){

  $user = Auth::user();
  return Redirect::to('admin/profile');

 }else{
      return Redirect::to('login');;
     }
```

and this is my `route.php`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function()
 {
   Route::resource('profile', 'AdminController', ['as'=>'package']);

  });
```

Now In the `AdminController.php` I have the method index() where I'm trying to get the id of the current loged in user. After the redirection from login page I can get the id of the user but when I refresh my profile page many times I lost the id of the user and he seems to be logout I get only 'sorry'.
this is my index method:

```
if (Auth::check()){

           echo 'ok';
           echo $id = Auth::user()->id;


        }else{
            echo 'sorry';
        }
```

How can I fix that? is it related to `laravel auth` with `Eloquent`? How can I get the id of the logged in user?

--edit---
If I just use `Route::post` I don't get this problem and I can easily get the user id.But I want to use `Route:Resource` with index,edit,update methods.

Comment: value of lifetime and expire_on_close in app/config/session?

Comment: 'lifetime' => 120 and 'expire_on_close' => false,

Comment: Hi Ghada, why are you setting the variable $user to Auth::user() in UserController? It does seem to be used. I'd like to help but need more information on what you're trying to accomplish. Wouldn't you normally have a route filter for admin area anyway? I.e. you should not be able to even access the Admin Index or AdminController methods if you are not logged in..right?

Comment: yes exactly.I'm using a filter for the route.He should be logged in to access the web page. I need to display the user informations in my page so that i'm using `$user=Auth::user()`

Answer (score 0):

Lifetime in `app/config/session` defines session lifetime(obviously) in seconds. so you can set it to a lot more than 120 and i think your problem will be solved.

Comment: Can you please increase it to 1200 may be

Comment: I increased and i still have the same problem